# Linked Table Valued Function Parameters (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a SQL Server TVF that takes a single param and then used that param to build the other required parameters. Is this even possible?

The error states incorrect syntax near 'LEFT'. Simple representation below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TESTFUNCTION
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PRM1 VARCHAR(2) = 'ABC',
    @PRM2 VARCHAR(1) = LEFT(@PRM1,1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    SELECT @PRM2
)
GO
```

Thank You!

Comment: Per [this post on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted) I have rolled back your question to the original version. You posted a question which already has an upvoted answer, then you made fundamental changes to the question. If you want to ask a different question, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

> BEFORE EDIT MADE IN THE QUESTION :

You need only one parameters :

```
SELECT @PRM2 = LEFT(@PRM1, 1);
```

However, you need *scaler* function not *table* valued function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION TESTFUNCTION
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PRM1 VARCHAR(2) = 'ABC'
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS 
   BEGIN

    DECLARE @PRM2 VARCHAR(255)

    SET @PRM2 = LEFT(@PRM1, 1)

    RETURNS (@PRM2)

   END
```

Note : Your `@PRM1` will accept only two characters which are `AB`. So, define appropriate length.

Comment: it seems param @PRM1 (or @Period, depending on edited OP) is a 6-digit date in the format YYYYMM, and @PRM2 (or @PeriodYear) thus a 4-digit year to be used as condition for a `SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE`

Comment: @devio. . . This has been answered before modification in the question.

Comment: I have rolled the question back to the version that you answered...

Comment: If you start with varchar(3), why would the **scalar** function need to return varchar(255)? Um - what does `RETURNS` do?